# sudo with original profile

Tags: sudo, home

I need to launch an app with root privileges, but the app requires access to the original user's profile....so just using sudo to start the app results in the app starting incorrectly.

How can I launch the app with root privileges so that it still uses the profile of the originally logged in user.

This is Mac OS X 10.10

Answer (score 1):

Applications normally read per-user files under the directory indicated by the environment variable `HOME`.

By default, sudo doesn't change the value of `HOME`, so it still points to the home directory of the original user. Several options can make sudo change it to the home directory of the target user, so make sure that none of them are turned on:

- Don't set the `always_set_home` option in the `sudoers` file.
- If you have the `env_reset` option set, include `HOME` in the `env_keep` list.
- Don't pass the `-H`, `-s` or `-i` command line options.

To set options in `sudoers` for just one command, use something like

```
Defaults !myapp env_keep+=HOME,!always_set_home
```

If the `HOME` variable is preserved, but the application doesn't look there, you'll need to find an application-specific way of telling it to heed the `HOME` variable rather than look in the effective UID's home directory.

Note that it's unusual to require that an application runs as root but reads files belonging to a physical user. Maybe these files should be in a system configuration directory instead?